# Can a US citizen work remotely for a Canadian company? What are the legal, tax and immigration standards?

Tags: immigration, canada, us-citizens, working

I am a US citizen, in the process of applying for a Canadian residence visa (I plan to move to Canada).

Having a job offer in hand during the application process definitely would help my chances of being issued an Invitation To Apply (ITA, which is part of the process), and I would ideally like to *have* a job right from the day I move.

My line of work is very remote-friendly.  Can I, as a US citizen, work from the US for a Canadian company?  What specific legal and tax standards would I have to meet for the US and for Canada?  And does active employment with a Canadian company count the same way as having a job *offer* from a Canadian company, in the immigration process?

Comment: "And does active employment with a Canadian company count the same way as having a job offer from a Canadian company, in the immigration process?" I don't know the answer to this, but this would usually be an entirely different visa altogether, or atleast a different version of the same visa.